# Issue with using CSS in JSP File

Tags: css, jsp

I am pretty new with Java web programming. I have a JSP page where I want to call a CSS file from it. I am trying to do this in Netbeans IDE.

I don't see any styling to my page. I am sure something is wrong with the path but I can't get it. Can someone pls let me know how to make it work

[image: Project Structure in Netbeans]

Below is my JSP code(home.jsp)

```
<%@page import="com.javadbproject.util.User"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Home Page</title>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<%User user = (User) session.getAttribute("User"); %>
<h3>Hi <%=user.getName() %></h3>
<strong>Your Email</strong>: <%=user.getEmail() %><br>
<strong>Your Country</strong>: <%=user.getCountry() %><br>
<br>
<form action="Logout" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Logout" >

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

A simple css file(loginstyle.css)

```
body
{
background-color:#d0e4fe;
}
h1
{
color:orange;
text-align:center;
}
p
{
font-family:"Times New Roman";
font-size:20px;
}
```

More details:

[image: Output Page and source]
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: what do you see in your generated HTML output source? is the path to the css file generated correctly?

Comment: I am deploying it to tomcat. So it would be a webpage in my local machine. I am sorry I don't know how could I find if CSS file is generating correct path

Comment: when you look at the page, press CTRL+U or right click and view the source.  verify what path you are generating.

Comment: @scunliffe The path looks fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **<c:url>** tag, which prepends the context path to an absolute URL.

**<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/css/loginstyle.css' />" />**

Comment: I am running into HTTP 500 error after modifying to above syntax

Comment: You need to add jstl.jar in your classpath & add this line on top of your jsp
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Comment: I included jstl.jar. I already have the reference to <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>. Doesn't change a thing. Only thing is I was able to get rid of 500 error but the page  remains the same

Comment: I am not getting any error whil accessing the webpage. I am just getting a page without any styling. Like a normal page without CSS effects. Please see my last screenshot in my original post

Comment: Have you tried this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loginstyle.css" />

Comment: Last time it errored out coz I didn't include jstl.jar and I used the syntax of it. Once I used that jar in my library I am able to access the page but still no CSS styling..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58309/discussion-between-rahul-jain-and-sandy).

Answer (score 0):

Got it by myself. I moved my CSS file to the directory where JSP resides and that solved the issue.